# Zoom out by scrolling in a testcafe test

Tags: testing, automated-tests, openlayers, testcafe, e2e

I have a map in my `angular` application `OpenLayers` map.
During the test using `testcafe`, I have to zoom out, but I have no way how to do that.
I only have to put my mouse at the center of the screen, and then scroll down to zoom out.
Already tried using `ClientFunction` with `scrollBy` and etc but nothing happens in map.
Thank you

Comment: You could use the OpenLayers view adjustZoom method https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html#adjustZoom  e.g. `map.getView().adjustZoom(-1)` to zoom out 1 level

Comment: @Mike Thanks but I have no access to the map. I'm in a separate project, doing tests

Answer (score 1):

Find out on which element the handler you need hangs and what event it listens to. This is most likely a 'mousewheel' event. This should help you:

```js
const zoom = ClientFunction(zoomSize => {
    const event = new WheelEvent('wheel', { deltaY: zoomSize });
    document.querySelector('#zommed-element').dispatchEvent(event);
});
```